# My Django Form Doesn't Add My Images To The Database

Tags: django, django-forms

I Tried To Add An Image To My Database But I Can Only Insert It Manually In My Admin Panel, It Doesn't Add It Automatically From My Form

This Is My `models.py`

```
    option1photo = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    option2photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    option3photo = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
```

And My `forms.py`

```
class AddpollForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = PollOptions
        fields = ['option1photo','option2photo','option3photo']
```

And My `views.py`

```
    polloptions_form = AddpollForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        polloptions_form = AddpollForm(request.POST)
        if polloptions_form.is_valid():            
            polloptions = polloptions_form.save(commit=True)

            return redirect('home')
```

Comment: It should be `AddpollForm(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any files in the form are put in `request.FILES` by Django. Also one should make sure their form tag has the following set: `enctype="multipart/form-data"` if they are submitting file data.

Your view should be like:

```
polloptions_form = AddpollForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    polloptions_form = AddpollForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if polloptions_form.is_valid():            
        polloptions = polloptions_form.save(commit=True)
        return redirect('home')
```

And your form tag when you are uploading files should be like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```